# Creating a DOM element with vanilla JS, it's not appearing in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom, append

I'm comparing two strings and want the result (how many common letters between them) to appear in the DOM and in the browser. I couldn't get it to work so I attempted to create a testNode, but no dice. I'm pretty iffy on DOM manipulation and JS in general, so I was wondering if someone could look at my code to see what's wrong.

Here's the .js:

---

```
var giantArray;
var computerChoice = function() {
  goalWord = shuffledWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * 29)];
};

computerChoice();
```

---

```
function countCommonCharacters(userWord, goalWord){
  var compareNum = 0;
  var check = Math.min(userWord.length, goalWord.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < check; i++) {
    if (userWord.charAt(i) === goalWord.charAt(i))
    compareNum++;
  }
  return compareNum;
}

var body = document.querySelector('body');
function showResult(result) {
  var div = document.createTextNode('testNode');
  div.textContent = "hello";
  div.setAttribute("id", "divID");
  div.body.style.color = 'green';
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}

var result = countCommonCharacters(userWord, goalWord);

showResult(result);
```

---

And here's the html:

```
<body>

  <div id="monitor"> <!-- level 1 -->

    <div class="landing"></div> <!-- level 2 -->

    <div id="screen"> <!-- level 2 -->

      <div class="panels"> <!-- level 3 -->

        <div id="bottomScreen"> <!-- level 4 -->

          <div class="bottomText"></div>

        </div>
```

### -----

Update:

```
var body = document.querySelector('body');
function showResult(result) {
  var elem = document.createElement('div');
  var div = document.createTextNode('testNode');
  div.textContent = "hello";
  div.setAttribute("id", "elem");
  div.body.style.color = 'green';
  elem.appendChild(div);
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
}
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: have you looked at the console and tried to debug your code? for example, errors like : `div.setAttribute is not a function`

Comment: You need **both** a `textNode` and an `element`, and `setAttribute` goes on the `element`, not the `textNode`.

Comment: @Claies actually that's the exact error message I'm getting

Comment: right, which is why I responded with the next comment.

Comment: @Claies Sorry, I didn't realize that both comments were yours. I made some updates (will add in a sec) but nothing's happening.

Comment: It's got to be `var div = document.createElement('div');` .